# Synchronise data between macOS and iOS Apps

Tags: ios, macos

I want to create applications using swift in iOS and macOS, which synchronise data records. What will be the best way to do it? Is it possible to use CloudKit? I read the containers can’t be used by two different apps. 
Is there another way I can use?

Comment: The most reliable way is CloudKit, however it's not an easy subject especially if you need also to store the data locally.

Comment: So I can use the data in CloudKit containers by more apps? I want to sync database records using in the swift app iOS and also in the swift App macOS

Comment: The CloudKit database is online. You can use it from all Apple platforms.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CloudKit. A container can be shared by two apps from the same developer. Just be sure to setup both apps with the same container id, not the default container.